# Can I receive notify event from PostgreSQL to waterline (node + sails)?

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

I use sails + node. I want to receive event/notify from pgsql to my system (waterline or sails). i have postgre function and trigger, but can not connect and receive notify/event from postgre. I have reserched sails/waterline docs but no success.

Comment: The underlying [node-postgres](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres) driver can do that, so perhaps you should just use it directly.

Comment: [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) does all that nicely. See the examples: [LISTEN / NOTIFY](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/Learn-by-Example#listen--notify).